# How to install OS X Server as a guest in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, osx-server

I am looking to install OS X Server 10.6 as a guest under Virtualbox on my iMac running OS X 10.6. Wondering if there are any caveats or issues regarding the hardware or the installation process. The Virtualbox manual was vague in regards to their warnings.

Is running an OS X Server guest restricted to an OS X Server host? Or can the host be the regular Snow Leopard client?

Currently having the following issue during the initial install:

```
Loading mach_kernel.mkext...

Could not open file 'mach_kernel.mkext'.....
```

iMac is 3GHz Core 2 Duo, 4 Gb RAM, iMac 10,1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update my original question, Apple changed their policies with OS X Lion 10.7 regarding the operating system being used in virtualized environments. They currently allow up to 2 instances of OS X Lion Server to be used in virtual environments.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't make any suggestions on the technical aspect, legally speaking this set up is fine. Mac OS X is only supposed to be installed on Apple hardware, but there is no distinction between Apple servers and desktop models - indeed, with the withdrawal of the Xserve, there is no physical difference between Apple server and desktop models other than lack of DVD drives and the software they ship with. If you buy it separately, OSX Server perfectly capable of being installed on most Macs - 10.5 and below even allowed installation on labtop models.

Comment: Legally speaking, it's entirely dependent on the country you're in anyway.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: can you add a link that confirms your statement?

Comment: @dag729 [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X#Mac_OS_X_auf_anderen_Computern) says, paraphrased: Apple's license forbids installation on non-Apple hardware, but it has not yet been determined in court whether they are allowed to restrict use of their software in that way (in Germany of course). It's similar (AFAIK, IANAL) to the situation of SB and OEM Windows copies that can legally be traded without being bound to a particular machine, because [of a decision of the German supreme court BGH in 2000](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erstausrüster#OEM-Software).

Comment: Even if it is the case that a hardware restriction would be illegal in Germany (or anywhere else) it wouldn't make the set up suggested not work, would it? What's being suggested would work even under the most draconian interpretation of the licence.

Comment: I'm only commenting on the legal aspect of your answer you stated in your first sentence (see my first comment). I concur with the rest and lack the VirtualBox experience to give an answer of my own. *Hint: If you reply to someone's comment, use @PrefixOfTheirUsername, e.g. @Daniel, so they get notified of your answer*

Comment: @Daniel Beck: it seems that the OP is talking about install OSX server on a iMac under VirtualBox; if this is the case, he's actually running OSX server on Apple hardware: Parallel, VirtualBox or VMWare won't change the hardware configuration nor the vendor itself, so no legal issue behind the corner.

Comment: @dag729 Yes of course, it's about server, and they changed those licensing rules with Leopard, if I'm not mistaken. I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @dag729 Now I remember what I intended to express with the original comment: The statement in the answer, while universally true, argues that it's only the case because of the OP's hardware -- which might be true in the US, but not e.g. in Germany, where the whole licensing issue might be non-existent. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Why are we all arguing about something we agree on? Apple's lawyers will not be coming after this person, whether it's because they're doing something allowed by the licence, or because they're doing something the licence cannot prohibit.

Comment: @Scott: I guess that we are all arguing about that in order to actually confirm our knowledge on the issue. "Agreed" --> "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" --> "Ok, we agree" :D